# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at node_modules_44004b._.js?ts=1699982222984:1:1) when using Next.js dynamic imports

Tags: next.js

I recently tried importing the components using `next/dynamic` to optimize first load JS size and these errors come on the browser console(in dev mode). All the error goes away when I revert all dynamic imports to normal imports.

```
import Header from "@/components/Headers/Main";
⇊⇊ (gives those error on console)
const Header = dynamic(() => import("@/components/Headers/Main"));
⇊⇊ (reverting clears error)
import Header from "@/components/Headers/Main";
```

[image]

What is this behaviour. Is this normal with dynamic imports?